# How can I move my app user to next level in android app

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am developing an android app for my university. In my app, there will be 3 phase (summer, spring, fall). At the beginning of each phase, new users will register to the app. I am using firebase database for storing those users information (name, id, course teacher etc). After the end of each phase, I want to move all my user to next phase automatically. For example, if it is the summer phase, then after the end of Summer phase all the user should automatically update to the next phase (Fall). How can I do that? Is there something to do with the database?

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: you need a cloud functions to call your API and look for people in the summer class, at the specific date, change those students in summer to fall and send that result back to the DB

Answer (score -1):

You need to write cloud function for that. Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/